# New to Alloy - what does int mean in the context of a run command?

Tags: alloy

Here's the alloy code for the example we're going over in my class:

```
abstract sig Airport {
    flight: set Airport
}
one sig CMX, DTW, MSP, BRD, CDG extends Airport {}

fact {
--  flight = CMX->DTW + DTW->MSP + MSP->CMX + DTW->CDG + CDG->DTW + MSP->BRD + BRD->MSP
}

fun flight2: Airport->Airport {flight.flight}
fun flight3: Airport->Airport {flight.flight2}
fun flight4: Airport->Airport {flight.flight3}
fun flight5: Airport->Airport {flight.flight4}

pred show {
    flight5 in flight2
    flight2 not in flight5
--  #flight = 10
}

run show for 5 Airport, 6 Int
```

I want to know what the last line means.  Specifically, what does "6 Int" mean?

Answer (score 3):

The last line defines an upperbound (called a scope) to the number of atoms conforming to the given concepts in any satisfying instance to be found when running this command.

In your example, you will look for instances which contains at most 5 Airport atoms.  Int is a built-in type in Alloy. As you didn't declare any Int-typed field, the part 6 Int won't have big impacts on the instance finding process.

The number associated to Int in the scope do not correspond to the maximum number of Int atom in instances to be found but to the bit-width to be used to represent Integers.
With a bit-width of 6, your instance will contains integers from -32 to 31.